# How do you code a typewriter effect in visual basic 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm creating a video game and I need to display text one character at a time and the rest of the internet has been of very little help as they're for older versions of visual basic that I know nothing about.

Here's my faulty code:

```
Dim outfile As IO.StreamWriter
Dim infile As IO.StreamReader

Private Sub StartScreen_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim strTitle As String = " "
    Dim strText() As String = {}
    Dim intLoop As Integer = 0

    If IO.File.Exists("save.txt") = False Then
        outfile = IO.File.CreateText("save.txt")
    End If

    infile = IO.File.OpenText("save.txt")
    Do Until infile.Peek = -1
        strText(intLoop) = infile.Read
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        intLoop += 1
    Loop
    intLoop = 0
    Do While strText.Length <> intLoop
        strTitle = strText(intLoop)
        lblTitle.Text = lblTitle.Text & strTitle
        intLoop += 1
    Loop
    infile.Close()
    outfile.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Why is your code faulty?  What's it doing (or not doing) that you don't understand?

Comment: It doesn't display the form at all

Answer (score 0):

Firstly - quite apart from your main problem - it appears that your `Thread.Sleep` is in the wrong place.  You're sleeping while you're reading the file into memory, but not while you're copying the text into your `lblTitle' - so you take ages to read the file, and then immediately copy the whole thing into the UI.  That's not the effect you're looking for: read the whole file, and put the delay in the second loop.

The reason that your form isn't displaying is that all of your code is in the `_Load` method of the form - and the form won't display until that's complete.  So, instead, your form is staying hidden for the same number of seconds as you have in your text.  It should appear eventually, but this isn't the effect you're after, I'm sure!

The most immediate way to handle this problem is to push all of your code into a separate method and call that method on a background thread.  This will allow your form to load and be displayed, and the background thread will continue to process your text.  However, you'll need to modify your code slightly as you can't modify your UI from a background thread.  Look up the `Invoke` and/or `BeginInvoke` methods for how to work around this.

The other solution is to take out your `Thread.Sleep(1000)`, move your code to a separate method, and call that method on a `Timer`.  The timer can fire once a second and add the next character of your text each time.  This will probably produce cleaner code, but you might want to make sure you're reading and closing the file straight away and not (as you're doing now) keeping the file locked until the entire process has finished.